# How to go back to an already launched activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to go back to an already launched activity without recreating again.

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
     this.startActivity(i);

    }
```

Instead of doing is there any other way to go back to another activity which is already created, which I get back with " Back button "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the `FirstActivity` declaration in your `AndroidManifest.xml` like so

```
<activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

You could also try the following if `SecondActivity` was started from `FirstActivity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     this.finish();
}
```

Comment: It works fine When using Finsih() but I'm getting an error ` Activity com.example.yasser.version6.EditText has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.` in the log cat is that fine ?

Comment: @YasserB. That error must be from some other code in your Activity. You wanna get that fixed. I think that's reserved for another question.

Comment: I'm getting this error only when I'm using finish()

Comment: @YasserB. Is a Dialog or similar thing open in your Activity? I suspect something is open that needs to be closed before calling finish()

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you start a new activity with an intent you can specify an intent flag like this:

```
// this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front 
// of its task's history stack if it is already running.
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

or

```
// If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an
// existing one, the current activity will not be counted as the top activity
// for deciding whether the new intent should be delivered to the top instead
// of starting a new one.
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

When starting SecondActivity do not finish the first activity so when you go back , you will be taken to the first activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your second Activity, close the Activity calling finish() instead of creating a Intent for the other screen.

By calling finish() the Application will go back in the Activity stack and show the previous Activity (if its not finished()).

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `finish()` on 1st Activity, when you start 2nd Activity. When `back` is pressed on 2nd Activity, it finishes itself and goes back to 1st Activity by default. `onCreate()` is not called for 1st Activity in this case. No need to override `onBackPressed()` in 2nd Activity.

However, Android can destroy 1st Activity when you are using 2nd Activity, to reclaim resources, or, if you have checked `Don't keep activities` in Developer options. In such case you can use `onSaveInstanceState()` to save data and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to use it again in 1st Activity. You can also get the saved data in `onCreate()`. [Here](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) is how it works. Also, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called only if android decides to kill the Activity and not when user kills the Activity(e.g. using back button).